# ActionBarSherlock SearchView with REST based suggestions

Tags: android, search

I'm trying to implement a search view within my ABS that retrieves suggestions from my backend while the user types, just like the Play Store app does with its search view. All the online documentation talks about search configurations, activities, content providers and intents. All I want is a simple autocomplete text edit that displays suggestions from my backend.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: can you post your answer..